# NetSuite Saved Search Result Is Blank

Tags: netsuite, shipping-method, saved-searches

I tried to create a saved search to pull information from the **"Shipping Method"** field under Item Fulfillment; while the result is not showing any information even there is information under the "Shipping Method field".

Please see the criteria and result as follows.

Can someone please suggest how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Criteria:
Main Line   is true
Type    is Item Fulfillment
Status  is Item Fulfillment:Picked
Date    is after 9/1/2019

Result:
Created From : Internal ID
Created From : Document Number
Shipping Method (Custom Body)
Shipping Carrier

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for Ship Via? That is NetSuite's native ship method field in a saved search.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping method field you have is a custom body field. It is not the native shipping method field, which is "Ship Via".

If you are setting a custom shipping method, that's ok, just as long as it's setup properly on your end. In this case, it may be, but you may be expecting different data as what you're describing is in the "Ship Via" field.

Comment: "Ship Via" is working now as I can see the data that I am looking for. Thank you so much!